# how to import QOH in odoo 8

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I want to update my stock in odoo either its by odoo frontend or using backend (postgres query).

I have my stock value in csv file.

Finally, I want to update quantity on hand in bulk.

Answer (score 5):

It's finally solved,  simply follow the step

**Step – 1 ;**

**1->**   select product in warehouse module  (open in list view).

**2->**  select the product which you want to update the inventory  .

**3->** click on more button and export  column

i-> product name and any other one if you needed .

you have file with name of **product.temlate.csv** .

**4->** Add a column qty and enter the quantity of product .

**Step – 2;**

**1->** select inventory adjustment in warehouse module  .

**2->** if you already have any created inventory then  go to 3rd point if not then create a inventory and feel the detail . and select all product option in Inventory of - :

**3->** now again click on inventory adjustment and select the inventory.

**4->** click on more and export the following column

***Inventories/location***

***Inventories/product***

***Invevtories/product Unit of Measure .***

Now you have one more file with name **stock.inventory.csv**

**Step -3 ->**

**1->** now add two column on **stock.inventory.csv**

First one is ***name*** and second is ***line_ids/product_qty***.

and remove the **id** column .

**2->** delete the value of column ***line_ids/product_id/id***    of **stock.inventory.csv**  file .

now copy the values of ***id*** column from **product.template.csv**  and paste into the ***line_ids/product_id/id***   column of **stock.inventory.csv**  .

**3->**  now copy the values of ***qty*** column from **product.template.csv**  and paste into the ***line_ids/product_qty*** column of **stock.inventory.csv**  .

**4->** enter any value in ***name*** column for your reference .

**Step – 4-**

make sure your file look like this file:-

Click on following link to see file

This is a sample of the succesfully imported data

http://bit.ly/odoocsv

***AFTER IMPORTING DONT FORGET START INVENTORY***

Comment: if any one needed any help then comment here

Comment: Hi, have you came across this error? I'm not sure the order of your steps are correct, I can only get the product_id constraint to pass if I manually add a quantity on hand for each project (which takes a long time of course!)

"insert or update on table "stock_inventory_line" violates foreign key constraint "stock_inventory_line_product_id_fkey" DETAIL: Key (product_id)=(20524) is not present in table "product_product". at row 2"
Any ideas? Many thanks

Comment: I have done this process for a month . It is correct .  first please tell me either you want to enter the quantity from Odoo  or directly into database .

Comment: What do you mean by "AFTER IMPORTING DONT FORGET START INVENTORY"

Comment: there is an option of start inventory . for using your inventory you have to start this inventory and delete previous one if u don't needed

Comment: I could not get this to work for me under Odoo 10.0. I get the same "insert or update on table "stock_inventory_line" violates foreign key constraint "stock_inventory_line_product_id_fkey" as the other user mentioned. Furthermore, the plugin mentioned below fails to install for me as well on Odoo 10.0.

Answer (score 0):

You can fill up stock by using physical inventory, it's available at

```
Warehouse -> inventory Control -> Inventory Adjustment
```

You can import your csv in odoo and fill up physical inventory.

```
stock.inventory
stock.inventory.line
```

These are the models that you have to used to update your stocks(Inventory Loss to Stock Location).

Answer (score 0):

Another easy option to update any odoo fields via frontend in bulk is to install MassEdit addon from: https://github.com/OCA/server-tools/tree/8.0/mass_editing

tested on odoo v8 and works great