# odoo10- Ambiguous specification for field 'Inventories', only provide one of name, external id or database id between rows 2 and 572

Tags: import, odoo-10, inventory, product-quantity

I tried to import inventory file from inventory adjustments in inventory of odoo 10
but I have the error

Ambiguous specification for field 'Inventories', only provide one of name, external id or database id between rows 2 and 572

the xlsc file is :

id  location_id/id  name    line_ids/product_id/id  Inventories/product Inventories/Checked quantities  line_ids/product_qty    line_ids/location_id/id Inventory_reference line_ids/product_uom_id/id

stock.stock_inventory_3 stock.stock_location_stock  Initial Inventory   **export**.product_template_7060     DONLE EZ CAST  1   1   stock.stock_location_components initial inventory   product.product_uom_unit

if I removed the line_ids/product_id/id , it give me no matching record found error
if i removed Inventories/product , it give me other error

my goal from this import to update on hand quantities of the products in inventory

Edit:

I followed this steps
[how to import QOH in odoo 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671399/how-to-import-qoh-in-odoo-8)
it is the same steps that I did
but I removed some columns
finally the final columns is:

name,line_ids/product_qty,line_ids/location_id/id,line_ids/product_id/id    line_ids/product_uom_id/id

but now other error appears

insert or update on table "stock_inventory_line" violates foreign key constraint "stock_inventory_line_product_id_fkey" DETAIL: Key (product_id)=(7060) is not present in table "product_product". between rows 2 and 572

I am sure that this product_id is present
as I exported it from inventory products

How can Solve this error

Please help
thanks

Comment: This tutorial may be help you, `https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z_KtCe9HSk`

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it before and it didnot work with me

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved

I followed the post [how to import QOH in odoo 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29671399/how-to-import-qoh-in-odoo-8)
and uploaded the products in free database
not demo database
then all errors disappears and the import succeedded